# Is there a way to execute a function only after scrollTo has finished executing?

Tags: react-virtualized

I have a `<List>` component. I am building a feature where it:

1. **Scrolls to a particular row in the `<List>`**. It does by using the `scrollToIndex` prop.
2. **Scrolls to a particular line in that row**. It does this by doing `document.getElementById('myId').scrollIntoView()`.

How can I ensure that step (2) occurs after step (1)?

**Note:** I have already tried the `onRowsRendered()` but it looks like that is not always executed after `scrollTo`.

Documentation is [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md#prop-types), but unfortunately I'm quite stuck.

---

**Edit:** In case anyone comes across this question in future, I got *kind of* an answer over at the GitHub repo:

> the `onScroll` prop you pass in is bound to the html `onscroll` event which is triggered every moment you scroll. The `scrollToIndex` prop is used to calculate the `scrollTop` and then is manually set on the html element.

https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/1077#issuecomment-381438215

Answer (score 2):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41111505/5683904

```
// Keep track of last scroll position
_lastScrollTop;
_cellRangeRenderer(props) {
    this._rowSizeAndPositionManager = props.rowSizeAndPositionManager;
    if (props.isScrolling === false && this._lastScrollTop !== props.scrollTop) {
        // Only call this function if
        this._lastScrollTop = props.scrollTop;
        this.onAfterScroll();
    }
    return defaultCellRangeRenderer(props);
}

onAfterScroll(){
  //Do what you want to do after scrolling has stopped.
}
```

In order to scroll to specific div in the DOM (2)

> document.getElementById('myId').scrollIntoView()

you have to ensure that the dom has already been rendered.

```
onNextFrame(callback) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
}
//And wrap the function that accesses the Dom directly like this
onNextFrame(() => {
            let target = document.querySelector(`...`);
            ...
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! So in the example above, how is `this.onAfterScroll()` different from the standard `onScroll` callback that you can provide to the `<List>` component directly?

Comment: It is only called after a scroll and scrolling has stopped